# jquery/javascript: arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, radio-button

I am a begginer with Javascript/jQuery and I hope someone can help me with the following:

I have a simple form (7 questions; 3 radio buttons/answers per question - except for question 5 with 8 possible choices ) and based on the selected answers, when user clicks on 'view-advice' I want to display relevant advices (combination of 38 possible advices) below the form.
I have given "a", "b", "c",... values to radio buttons and I am collecting them in an array.
The part where the script alerts the array works ok.
I can't figure out the part where I display the advices depending on the values in the array.

I'd appreciate your help! Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
var laArray = new Array();

$('.button-show-advice').click(function(){

    $(":radio:checked").each(function(i){
        laArray[i] = $(this).val();
        if (laArray == ["a","d","g","j","m","u"]) {
        $("#advice-container, #advice1, #advice2").show(); // something is wrong here :(
            };
    })
    alert(laArray) // testing to see if it works

})
```

Comment: Please add the html code

Comment: It is better practice to declare an array as: var laArray = [];

Comment: HTML of the form:
http://jsfiddle.net/tschardak/HQeXH/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than test for equality, I think the better means is to check whether or not each of your values are in the array using the [jQuery `inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function.

Granted, this is just the beginning of code.  You could probably write a function to shore this up, like so.

```
function radioSelected(val) {
  return ($.inArray(val, laArray) != -1);
}
```

and adapt it to your existing script.

Comment: i have tried to add the HTML of the form, but I got an error saying I can't add that much without credits....

Comment: thank you for the reaction, villecoder.
unfortunately, to a beginner like me you have to draw it ;)

the way I thought it would work the best is if I compare the choices against all possible of arrays/all possible combinations of selected radios, rather than check one by one. because every choice has too many advices that go with it...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare arrays this way you should probably
either compare each element of the 2 arrays

```
function compare_array(array1,array2) {
    var i;
    for(i=0;i=array1.length;i++) {
        if(array1[i]==array2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

or serialize the array in a comparable form ( comma separated string for example )

```
function compare_array(array1,array2) {
     return array1.join(",")==array2.join(",");
}
```

Comment: Compare with serializing, nice! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see the HTML code. But I guess you want to do something like this:

---

```
var laArray = [];
var compareValues = function(arr1, arr2) {
  $(arr1).each(function(index, el) {
   if(el !== arr2[index]) {
     return false;
   }
  });
  return true;
};

$('.button-show-advice').click(function(){
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(i){
        laArray.push($(this).val());        
    });
   if(compareValues(laArray,["a","d","g","j","m","u"])) {
      $("#advice-container, #advice1, #advice2").show();
   }  
});
```

*EDIT: updated the code, forgot the }); ...*

Comment: I appreciate your help very much, Nisse! However, this solution didn't seem to work. since I can't post the HTML here I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I forgot the missing }); in the end of the each-loop. Try to copy the example again.

Comment: var a = [1,2,3];

var compareValues = function(arr1, arr2) {
  $(arr1).each(function(index, el) {
   if(el !== arr2[index]) {
     return false;
   }
  });
  return true;
};
compareValues(a, [1,2,3]); //true

Comment: excellent! your solution works :)
thank you very much, Nisse!

hold on, now comes even more ignorant question...
if i need to repeat the below step (changing just the values and the elements to be shown):

if(compareValues(laArray,["a","d","g","j","m","u"])) {
      $("#advice-container, #advice1, #advice2").show();
   }  
... would that be a horrible thing to do?

Comment: If you can't post your HTML here, then insert all of your code to http://jsfiddle.net and submit the link here.

Comment: thanks again! but, I apologize, because I don't understand what to do with the two alerts I have now. 
...still wondering if i can repeat the below step form your first solution and compare to ["b","d","g","j","m","u"]... etc (all possible cobminations>
 if(compareValues(laArray,["a","d","g","j","m","u"])) {
      $("#advice1, #advice2").show();
   }

Comment: i think i got it all wrong, still trying to implement your script but keep on getting stuck. any suggestions? now i am trying to figure out if the idea of checking each value with in Array is better solution in this case...